# Match 8 digits or 1-8 digits and an asterisk

Tags: regex

I am creating a search box to search for a number that has 8 digits OR a wild card search.  It should only allow one optional asterisk at the end or the beginning:

```
Valid results
12345678
87654321
1112223*
12*
1345*
*123456*
*1234567
*1*    

Invalid results
1234567
A
12-
12@
**
**1234**
&T(
*
*1*2*
89789A8
```

Trying to create a regular expression to solve this.  I currently have this:

```
"\d{8}"
```

But it only allows for 8 digits and not the '*' character at the beginning or ending.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 8 digits, or 1-7 digits with a star at beginning or end, or 1-6 digits with a star at beginning and end:

```
"\d{8}|\d{1,7}\*|\*\d{1,7}|\*\d{1,6}\*"
```

You didn't mention your regex flavor, but since you used `{8}` I assume it can handle ranges. Otherwise, you'll need something like `\d\d?\d?\d?\d?\d?`.

You may need anchors depending on the language used and the options used to invoke the regular expression, in which case you would have

```
"^(\d{8}|\d{1,7}\*|\*\d{1,7}|\*\d{1,6}\*)$"
```

Online tester (using multiline and global to show all matches here): https://regex101.com/r/uQ1yY8/1

Comment: Thanks.  One little comment.  [asterisk] 1 [asterisk] should be valid.

Comment: This allows both `**1234**` and `*1*2*`.

Comment: @meatspace: Did you mean to comment on the other answer? Mine doesn't match either.

Comment: Don't forget the anchors

Comment: @anubhava: Right, depends on the flavor used, but I'll add a note.

Comment: meatspace you are right.  it is allowing  [asterisk][asterisk]1234[asterisk][asterisk]  which should be invalid.

Comment: @meatspace: You're asking for a substring match not an entire match. You can add anchors to simulate the former with the latter. See the note in my answer.

Comment: @anubhava: Yes, that's almost identical to the one I added to my answer. :)

Comment: Yes I know and I've already upvoted your answer. My comment was in response to meatspace's comment

Comment: Good job anubhava !  Your "working demo" in the comments above works 100%.  Thanks Charles, good job also.

Answer (score 1):

one possible regexp:

```
\d{8}|\*?(\d{1})+\*
```

Probably it will need a "$" at the end (depending of your RE engine).

UPDATE1:

Good point, I missed that one. A better version:

```
^\*?(\d{1})+\*?$
```

UPDATE2:

```
^\*?(\d{1,7})\*$|^\*(\d{1,7})\*?$|^\d{8}$
```

Comment: Thanks!  Quick question.  Does [asterisk]1234567 show as valid to you?  Its #7 in the valid results above.

Comment: Thanks saw the update.  But its marking 1234567 as valid now:  https://regex101.com/r/kE0lG6/1

Comment: my UPDATE2 passes the test case ;)

Comment: Yes it does.  Thank you devwebcl!